# SQL Server CE : how can I combine results of two queries into one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have two queries that return a single value, from different tables (and not joined via a relationship in any way), and I'm trying to combine both queries' outputs onto a single row, however I'm getting a syntax error. This is what I'm trying:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT Timestamp As StartDate 
     FROM Events 
     WHERE Description = 'Inserted') AS StartDate,
    (SELECT TOP (1) Timestamp As EndDate 
     FROM DataStore 
     ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) AS EndDate
```

And this is what I'm getting back:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token
>   line offset = 2,Token in error = SELECT ]

Query 1 on its own returns: "2015-06-10 11:43:34.000" and Query 2 returns: "2015-06-11 13:59:47.000"

I want to return a single row with two columns, with the output of query 1 as the "StartDate" column, and the output of query 2 as the "EndDate" column.

Comment: select ... UNION ALL select ...?

Comment: Nope, that's not what I want. It returns the queries as two seperate rows, and also seems to alter the returned data for each too :/

Comment: So show us what query 1 and query 2 return, and the wanted combined result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL CE does not support nesting SELECT statments like this, so you have to use two SELECT statements and use UNION or call ExecuteNonQuery twice.

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to just call the query twice.

Answer (score 1):

The first query might return 2 or more values unlike the second query. 
Try putting a `TOP (1)` also in the first query since I think you're just gunning for the top results.

```
SELECT
(SELECT TOP (1) Timestamp As StartDate FROM Events WHERE Description = 'Inserted') AS StartDate,
(SELECT TOP (1) Timestamp As EndDate FROM DataStore Order by Timestamp DESC) AS EndDate
```

See this [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e1e2/2) for the test that I did.

Comment: Nope, still get the same error. And both queries definitely return only a single value each.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @q1 as varchar(max)
declare @q2 as varchar(max)
SELECT @q1= Timestamp FROM Events WHERE Description = 'Inserted' 
SELECT TOP (1) @q2= Timestamp FROM DataStore Order by Timestamp DESC
select @q1 as StartDate, @q2 as EndDate
```

Comment: Nope, that's giving me: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 53,Token in error = Order ]"

Comment: No, the results are still on two seperate rows.

Comment: then please edit your question and show us the expected output

Comment: @JohnBergqvist This might probably not the best solution, but see my edited answer now. It will work in any condition.

Comment: Still no i'm afraid: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = declare ]"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT StartDate.StartDate, EndDate.EndDate
FROM
(SELECT Timestamp As StartDate FROM Events WHERE Description = 'Inserted') AS StartDate
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT TOP (1) Timestamp As EndDate FROM DataStore Order by Timestamp DESC) AS EndDate
```

Comment: Well Timestamp is the column name. The queries both work individually, just not together.